# Date is not rendered in Django-Crispy-Forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using crispy-forms with bootstrap datepicker, I can save the form, but in edit page the date is not showing in template.

This is the code:

In editForm():

```
def init(self, *args, **kwargs):
self.helper = FormHelper()
Div('date_end', id="date_end", template='project/util/datepicker_end.html'),
```

The datepicker_end.html:

```
    <div class="input-append date" id="date_end" data-date="{% now 'd-m-Y' %}" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    <label for="id_date_end">Date end:</label>
    <input type="text" name="date_end" id="id_date_end" readonly="readonly" class="input-small"><span id="datepicker-icon" class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
    </div>
```

The output of "print form"(the date is comming in form, but is not rendered in the "div"):

```
<tr><th><label for="id_date_end" class="required">Date end: *</label></th><td><input type="text" name="date_end" value="31-05-2012" id="id_date_end" /></td></tr>
```

This result in a empty field:
http://postimage.org/image/r9wqfyrvf/

Link to project: https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms

Link to doc: http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/d-0/index.html

EDIT!

I found the solution.
Instead of using in template the input html tag , used the normal tag django {{form.date_end}}. The same template is used for the registration form.

The template datepicker_end.html using the django tag {{form.date_end}} instead a normal html input.

```
<div id="div_id_data_end" class="clearfix control-group">
    <div class="input-append date" id="date_end" data-date="{% now 'd-m-Y' %}" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
            <label class="control-label requiredField" for="id_date_end">Data end* </label>
            <div class="controls">
                    {{form.date_end}}<span id="datepicker-icon" class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>        
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In forms.py

```
class EditForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = MyModel

self.helper.layout = Layout(  
        Fieldset(
        [...]
        Field('date_end', css_class='input-small dateinput', id='date_end', readonly='readonly', template='project/util/datepicker_end.html'),
)
```

Regards!